# PySpark Rdd to Dataframe very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which at one point I convert to rdd to perform a custom calculation. Before this was done using a UDF (creating a new column) , however I noticed that this was quite slow. 
Therefore I am converting to RDD and back again, however I am noticing that the execution seems stuck during the conversion of rdd to dataframe.

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster(server_location).setAppName("MoleculesTests")

ss = SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf).getOrCreate()
ss.sparkContext.addPyFile("helpers.py")

def mapper(line):
    fields = line.split(' ')
    return Row(name=str(fields[0]))

def calculate_tanimoto(smiles1,smiles2):
    try:
        mol1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles1)
        mol2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles2)
        fp1 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol1, 2)
        fp2 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol2, 2)
        similarity = DataStructs.FingerprintSimilarity(fp1,fp2, metric=DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity)

        return similarity
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
        print ("Error Smiles1", smiles1, " 2", smiles2)


CREATE_VECTORS = False
SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD = 0.3
dataFile = '../mols/compounds18.smi'
lines = ss.sparkContext.textFile(dataFile)

smiles = lines.map(mapper)
schemaSmiles = ss.createDataFrame(smiles).cache()
schemaSmiles.createOrReplaceTempView("smiles")

#some basic filtering
valid_smiles = ss.sql("SELECT * FROM smiles WHERE name != 'smiles'")
valid_smiles_id = valid_smiles.select("*").withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

#cartesian join and then filtering to get only upper triangle of a similarity matrix, with result being Source_Id, Source_description, Target_id, Target_description
combinations = valid_smiles_id.alias("source").join(valid_smiles_id.alias("target") )\
    .where("source.Id <= target.Id")\
    .select(f.col("source.Id").alias("source_id"), f.col("source.Name").alias("source_smile"), f.col("target.Id").alias("target_id"),f.col("target.Name").alias("target_smile"))


 #Change to rdd to perform calculate_tanimoto using source and target descriptions 
combinations_rdd = combinations.rdd.map(tuple)
similarities_fp = combinations_rdd.map(lambda (source_id, source_smiles,target_id,target_smiles): (source_id, target_id, calculate_tanimoto(source_smiles, target_smiles)))\
                              .filter(lambda (a,b,c): c >= SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD).cache()


schema = StructType([StructField("source",IntegerType(), False),StructField("target",IntegerType(), False),StructField("tanimoto",StringType(), False)])
#change back to Dataframe, execution seems to get stuck here
combinations_sim = ss.createDataFrame(similarities_fp,schema=schema).cache()
print(combinations_sim.show(n=10))
combinations_sim = combinations_sim.groupby(combinations_sim.source_id).agg(f.collect_set("target_id"))
```

Running this for 2500 compounds seems to get stuck.

Comment: First and foremost you are taking brute force approach to the problem. It cannot work well, and it definitely cannot work well. Also, you add significant overhead by using `DataFrame` at all, and parsing each smiles multiple times. Consider using proper molecular indexes, or even general purpose similarity tools (LSH and such). And to be honest using Spark to process 2500 records is a serious (and expensive) overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 2500 is simply to test the implementation. This wil be used for more instances. With regards to the use of dataframe, i used it because it is said that they are more optimised than rdds. I do have an rdd implementation with which i am comparing to. Wrt smiles, I have yet to find a way to store a fingerprint object in dataframe if it is possible. My concern was that i was doing something incorrect as it was taking more than 10 minutes to simply convert rdd to dataframe